# win8 dos not show ubuntu machine in networking

Tags: 12.10, samba, windows-8

I have a ubuntu machine running several samba shares. my windows 7 pcs show this machine in file explorer under networking.  when I click on it I can see my shares and access them.  However my windows 8 laptop does not show the machine under networking.  I have to tell windows to map the network drive and set it up that way.  Does anyone know how to get the comp to show up under networking so I don't have to have each share mounted as a drive?  I just find it looks less cluttered in file explorer that way

Comment: I am able to open it under networking by using run with \\ipaddress but this only stays till I close the windows explorer window and also displays the ipaddress rather than the machine name.  I would like for it to appear whenever I go to the networking section like my other machines and display the machine name. also for what it is worth the dlna server's on the machine show up properly

Answer (score 0):

You need to install avahi-daemon. It will advertise the name of the ubuntu computer on the network. `sudo apt-get install avahi-daemon`